# How to call Obj C custom Init method of a NSOperations subclass from Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsoperation

I have a subclass of NSOperation and custom `init` method which can take couple of arguments. this class is written in OBJ C. and I wanted to call this init method from Swift class for unit testing. is there a way I can call the init method directly from swift? Compiler couldn't recognize the init method.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a bridging header and import the ObjC class there. Then that class will be available in all of your swift classes

1. Add a new file to Xcode (File > New > File), then select “Source” and click “Header File“.
2. Name your file “YourProjectName-Bridging-Header.h”. ...
3. Create the file.
4. Navigate to your project build settings and find the “Swift Compiler – Code Generation” section.  You may find it faster to type in “Swift Compiler” into the search box to narrow down the results.  Note: If you don’t have a “Swift Compiler – Code Generation” section, this means you probably don’t have any Swift classes added to your project yet.  Add a Swift file, then try again.
5. Next to “Objective-C Bridging Header” you will need to add the name/path of your header file.  If your file resides in your project’s root folder simply put the name of the header file there.  Examples:  “ProjectName/ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h” or simply “ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h”.
6. Open up your newly created bridging header and import your Objective-C classes using #import statements.  Any class listed in this file will be able to be accessed from your swift classes.

Above info was found here: http://www.learnswiftonline.com/getting-started/adding-swift-bridging-header/

Comment: I have a bridging header file already placed. I could able to access the class except the Init method. is there any reason for that. If I create the same subclass in swift file I could access the init method with the following syntax      nsoperationsubclass(initmethod arguments)

Comment: Can you show the code snippet for your initializer?

Comment: It's easier to have Xcode make a bridging header for you tbh. Just make a new Objective C file in a Swift project, or vice versa

Comment: @Richmond Watkins interface customOperation:NSOperation -(id)initWithPersistenceStack:(PersistenceStack*)pStack; end in .m file -(id)initWithPersistenceStack:(PersistenceStack*)pStack{ self = [super init]; if (self){ self.pStack = pStack;} return self;}end trying to access it like this in swift let op = customOperation(pStack) or customOperation().initWithPersistenceStack(pStack)